# Unable to create gitconfig file for user

Tags: git

I have installed git as root on my Linux (debian) system before I had created my user. After I created the user I try to run the command (as the new user):

```
git config --global user.name "myusername"
```

But I get the error:

```
error: could not lock config file /home/<username>/.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

When I type

```
git config --global --edit
```

It starts my editor with the path `/home/<username>/.gitconfig`. I think this is really weird. I have tried to create the .gitconfig file by creating it as **sudo** and then move the .gitconfig file from `/root/.gitconfig` to `/home/<username>/.gitconfig` and lastly **chown** it to my user, but that does not work either. 
Please help me..

---

EDIT: 
The problem had to do with user permissions on the home directory of the user. I just ran:

```
sudo chown username:username /home/username
```

And then it worked as usal.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374481/836169) to this related question.

Answer (score 4):

Before you go borderline insane, just edit/insert the username by hand inside the `.gitconfig`? Open it up with the editor of your choice and go ahead:

## gitconfig excerpt from me:

```
[user]
        name = myusername
        email = mymailaddress@mymailprovider.tld
[color]
        branch = on
        diff = on
        interactive = on
        status = on

...
```

The `user`**.**`name` from the commandline is the `[user]` + `name =` combo in the config.
 `name` is just indented with a tab.

Comment: But the problem is that it doesn´t exists in the userspace? Ok but ill try and do it by hand... Ill come back to you, thanks

Comment: My problem solutions is above, see if interested, thanks for your collaboration and your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Install git

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ sudo apt-get install git
```

....Set up your user

```
vagrant@precise32:/$ sudo useradd -m yourusername
vagrant@precise32:/$ sudo passwd yourusername
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
vagrant@precise32:/$ su - yourusername
Password: 
$ ls
$ pwd
/home/yourusername
```

...Configure git

```
$ git config --global user.name "yourusername"
$ ls -a
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .gitconfig  .profile
$ cat .gitconfig
[user]
    name = yourusername
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I have tried but doesn´t work. I get the ´error: could not lock config file /home/<username>/.gitconfig: Permission denied´ as wrote in the post

Comment: My problem solutions is above, see if interested, thanks for your collaboration and your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try this if this works for you

```
mkdir ~/.git 
git config --global user.name= <name>
```

Comment: My problem solutions is above, see if interested, thanks for your collaboration and your suggestion.