# "Git error: could not lock config file C:/Users/old_profile/.gitconfig: No such file or directory" after profile migration

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I have an interesting error that keeps coming up when using git for windows (version 2.12.0.windows.1). I recently migrated my windows profile directory from one location to another.

For some git commands I get the error:

`error: could not lock config file C:/Users/<my old profile>/.influxdb/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
error: could not lock config file C:/Users/<my old profile>/.influxdb/.gitconfig: No such file or directory`

Note: This error always comes up twice, for example if I try to do `git config --global diff.tool p4merge`

What is interesting is that this folder it's looking for doesn't exist, and if i use `git config -l --show-origin` to see where git is getting it's settings, it makes no mention of this path, and if I look inside any `CONFIG` files I can see no reference to this non-existant path.

Where is git storing a reference to this old path? I need to update it as I think this error is stopping some commands working.

Answer (score 10):

I faced similar issue.

> Error: could not lock config file C:/.gitconfig:

**Solution:** I  had a system environment variable (`Home= C:\` ) in my computer  and it caused this issue. Deleted it and everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

This was being caused by bad paths in my environment variables (due to the profile migration).

I opened up System Properties -> Environment Variables, and updated all references to `C:\Users\<old_profile>` with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

### In WSL / bash

**Use sudo** to set values. This should only apply to the `--system` scope.

```
sudo git config --system diff.tool p4merge
```

### In Cmd / PowerShell

**Run as Administrator** to set values. This is because the `gitconfig` file (probably located at: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\`) is protected.

Only `SYSTEM` and `COMPUTER\Administrators` have `Modify` rights. The rest of the ACLs have `Read` and `Read & execute` rights only.

[image: ACL List]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the same:

> “Git error: could not lock config file C:/<Name_file>/.gitconfig: No
> such file or directory”

1. I saw that *"C:/<...>/*" **no any files,** and I found file ".gitconfig" in ***C:/Users/profile/******.gitconfig***
2. I did **copy-paste .gitconfig** to C:/<...> and reload PC, after **Run git as Administrator** and all worked correct.