# How to fix "Filename too long error" during git clone

Tags: java, windows, git, github, gitlab

I am trying to take a git clone from a particular branch of my bitbucket repository using the below command:
`git clone <url> --branch <branchname>`.

However, I am getting the below error while taking the clone:

> error:unable to create file foldername/nodemodules/......: Filename
>   too long.

I tried resolving this by running the below command in my git cmd
`git config --system core.longpaths true`.

But I am getting:

> error: could not lock config file c://.gitconfig: Permission denied
>   error: could not lock config file c://.gitconfig: Invalid argument.

How do I solve these two errors?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917131/git-error-could-not-lock-config-file-c-users-old-profile-gitconfig-no-such

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

1. Start Git Bash **as Administrator**
2. Run command `git config --system core.longpaths true`

Another way (only for this clone):

`git clone -c core.longpaths=true <repo-url>`

Comment: hey thanks!! This worked for me. git clone -c core.longpaths=true <repo-url>

Comment: and if you are using a UI tool and the above didn't help.. .. >> Solution >> add "longpaths=true" to core section as described above>> C:\Users[---YOU-- ]\AppData\Local\Fork\gitInstance\2.20.1\mingw64\etc\gitconfig (For Fork on windows 10)

Comment: It seems we can not execute this if we don't have administrator access to the computer.

Answer (score 35):

Instead of `git config --system core.longpaths true`
try:

```
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

`--system` will set the variables for all users on the system, but what you are looking for is to the set it for currently logged in user.

Answer (score 13):

You can try setting long path with command (as Administrator):
`git config --system core.longpaths true`

Comment: you must execute with administrator permission

Comment: If you only need to make the change for a single repository you can run without the --system and it doesn't require admin permission: `git config core.longpaths true`

Answer (score 6):

If command `git config core.longpaths true` not worked then try changing it manually.

Go to `.git` folder of your project (make sure you are enabled hidden items view in file explorer) and Open the `config` file. File content will look like below

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<domain>/scm/<project>/<repo>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Add `longpaths = true` property manually under `[core]` section. Save it and try pulling the code from fresh git bash session. It will solve the issue.

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
        longpaths = true
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows there is a maximum file name length limit of 260 characters.

See https://superuser.com/questions/811146/windows-7-file-name-length-limited-to-129-characters for how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I was not having admin rights. So I had to go to config file in .git folder (hidden) in the same folder that you started the clone in local machine .
Then add `longpaths = true` under `[core]` .Run `git reset --hard origin/xxx` from Git Bash. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we need to set a variable "longpaths" as true in our local git config file under core section.

You can navigate to it at path

```
<git-repo>\.git\config
```

alternatively you can clone your code using git bash with below command

```
git clone -c core.longpaths=true <repo-url>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding *longpaths = true* under [core] followed by Runnig *git reset --hard origin/xxx* from Git Bash. This worked for me.

Comment: Please take the [tour], then read [answer]. Duplicate answers and answers that say "thank you" are not good answers.