# Seeing "The filename or extension is too long" when "terragrunt plan" is executed in Windows

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, hashicorp

Executing "terragrunt plan" from Visual Studio code gives the below error in Windows 10:

Running command: terraform init -backend-config=region=eu-west-2 -backend-config=bucket=bucket-name" -backend-config=dynamodb_table=lock-table -backend-config=encrypt=true -backend-config=key=ec2/terraform.tfstate

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...

- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.36.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.36.0...

Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/aws v3.36.0: mkdir
.terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.36.0/windows_amd64:
The filename or extension is too long.

[terragrunt] 2021/05/19 15:39:20 Hit multiple errors:
exit status 1

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Rubens for suggesting using `TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD` environment variable. I'm able to work around this problem.

Here are the complete steps in terragrunt:

1. from cmd, set TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD and call init:

```
set TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD=C:\\.terragrunt-cache

terragrunt init
```

2. Then copy or move `C:\\.terragrunt-cache` content to the `.terragrunt-cache` in my project (better clean up the folder first)
3. from cmd, unset TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD and call apply

```
set TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD=

terragrunt apply
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper fix is here:

1. Start Git Bash as Administrator
2. Run command `git config --system core.longpaths true`

[How to fix "Filename too long error" during git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699177/how-to-fix-filename-too-long-error-during-git-clone)

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem today and I solved by creating a `TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD` environment variable.

I set the value to `TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD=C:\.terragrunt-cache`.

Got this solution from this issue
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/581#issuecomment-460051767

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Was able to test this using: `TERRAGRUNT_DOWNLOAD=C:\.terragrunt-cache terraform init`

Answer (score -1):

I had faced similar issue on terraform init. I installed latest version of terraform and it got resolved.